# Methods and Counting in Java

Tags: java, methods, counting

•Write a method called showCharacter which takes a String and a position and writes out to the screen the character at the position indicated.

•Write a main method that asks the user for a String and a position. If the position is longer than the String, or the position is negative, it will keep prompting the user for a valid position. Main will call showCharacter with the String and the position.

Code in java
This is what i have and it works and it runs but when i enter 0 it will crash

```
  package com.company;
  import java.util.Scanner;
  public class Main {
  public static void showCharacter(String name, int pos) {
    System.out.println(name.charAt(pos-1));
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String word;
    int pos;
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a word");
    word = kb.nextLine();


    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a position. ");
         pos = kb.nextInt();

        if (pos >=0 && pos < word.length()) {

            break;
        }
        System.out.println("Invalid Option. Try again.");

    }

    showCharacter(word, pos);

    }}
```

Comment: `System.out.println(name.charAt(pos+1));`

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to subtract 1 from the position like this:

`showCharacter(word, pos - 1);`

The reason for this is that indexes in **most** programming languages start at `0` and represents the first value in an array. For example, by subtracting 1 from your input position, you'll get 0 when the input is 1 and you'll get the first value in an array of any datatype.

Comment: Thank you i just figured that out as you were typing, however now when i enter 0 my code crashes

Answer (score 0):

In showCharacter()
`System.out.println(name.charAt(pos-1))`

Change to `pos >=1`
If user enters position = 0, return with invalid position